Using RS-232 in linux
I have a panel pc which runs ubuntu server 22.04 and has a RS-232 port for communication. I bought a RS-232 to ttl module and connect ttl side to my raspberry pi 4 to create a serial communication. I echo "hello" into /dev/ttyS0 on panel pc but in rpi side nothing received. How can I check if appropriate driver for RS-232 is installed on pannel pc or not? Or even I use a correct device to send data in /dev or not?
Any suggestion would be helpfull.

I guess the first step would be to connect your the RS232 side of your RS232-to-ttl module to something else -- like a PC with a serial port -- and confirm that it works and that you have the Pi configured correctly (you may need to enable the serial port, for example).

Unfortunatly I do not have any other device with rs232 port

There are a number of things you have to get right to make RS232 work:

RX/TX matching
protocol settings: baud rate, character bit width, parity, stop bits
flow control

Note that RS232 is not a bidirectional bus, it is two separate unidirectional communication paths, one for RX and one TX.  To make two devices talk to each other, the RX from one device has to be connected to the TX of the other and vice versa.   Some devices are prewired so this happens (DCE to DTE), others need a "null modem" adapter or cable (DCE to DCE or DTE to DTE), which just swaps the RX/TX wires.  If you get this wrong, neither device will see any data.  This is the most likely problem.
Most modern devices use 8n1 (8 bit characters, no partiy, 1 stop bit).  If you have a mismatch for this, you may see some data pass, but it will be garbled or partially rejected as parity errors.
If you have a baud rate mismatch, there is a small chance some garbled data may be seen, but it is just as likely that nothing will be detected.  Some systems are able to automatically detect baud rate and match it, but most do not.
The minimum wiring for RS-232 to work requires 3 wires (ground, RX, TX), but it also includes hardware flow control lines (RTS/CTS) which are optional (software flow control can be used instead) as well as device detect lines (DTR / CD).  In a minimal 3 wire connection, a null modem would swap just RX and TX, but in a fully wired connection, all three pairs may need to be swapped.
The device /dev/ttyS0 would be your first integrated hardware serial port for which the driver is built in.  If you were using a USB adapter instead, it would be /dev/ttyUSB0 or /dev/ttyACM0 but you should check syslog or dmesg for USB insertion messes ages to get the device name.  You can use a command like stty 9600 < /dev/ttyS0 to set the baud rate.  Don't forget to set the baud rate the same on both ends.
You may also want to check if anything else has the port open with sudo lsof /dev/ttyS0.  Note that on default linux configurations you don't need to be root for normal use of the port (open, stty) if you are in group dialout.

Thanks for your insightful message. Would you give me some practical hints specifically for linux env?

I've added a few linux specific things but once you've got the right device, it's critical to get the rest of the things i listed right, mostly in the order I listed them.

Thanks, I do another experiment and change grub setting so that linux console output redirects to ttyS0 and after reboot I can get boot log in putty succesfully and i can send or receive data without any problem. But if i disable console log on ttyS0 I can not send or receive anything. I do not understand what is the realtion between them. I can not let logs to print in ttyS0 port because I want use it as data port and logs destroy my data. This is the part i changed in /etc/default/grub file:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200"

Probably the difference is that you need to set the protocol parameters on the port.  Try stty -a < /dev/ttyS0 with and without the console connection and check the differences.

Yes it was the problem! Thanks a lot :)
